Dynamic Pivot in CTE query set up having multiple queries
I have a CTE query set up like output of 1 is the input of next query and have a PIVOT in between. What is the correct syntax to use the dynamic PIVOT sql in cte2 in this template. I get error when I use it in the cte2. I am using SQL Server
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
), cte2 AS (
    --Dynamic Pivot of row values to column names using SET and DECLARE
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Get the distinct values from the column to be pivoted
    SELECT @cols = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([type])
        FROM cte1 
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')

    -- Build the dynamic SQL query
    SET @query = 'SELECT account_id, country,' + @cols + '
    FROM (
        SELECT  TOP 100 o.account_id, o.country, type, amount
        FROM cte1 as o  
    ) x
    PIVOT (
        SUM(amount)
        FOR [type] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p'

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL query
    EXEC sp_executesql @query

    -- end of pivot query
), -- end of cte2

cte3 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte2 --output data of pivot query to be used as input here
    WHERE Country = 'USA'
) --end of cte3 for New Business


You can't embed sql in a CTE, nor can you access CTE inside dynamic sql, actually nothing in your query after cte2 is legal SQL. If you want dynamic pivot, you have to type out the whole select inside the dynamic sql, then fetch the data and then re-code all the CTEs etc in another dynamic SQL. If you can't do it, it means you're not ready for pivots and should hit one of billions of previous pivot questions on stackoverflow

Aside... if you're on SQL Server 2017 or later you can ditch the STUFF FOR XML hackery for STRING_AGG().

Does this answer your question? SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?

It was an interesting idea, but you can't do it this way. If your intent is to reuse the results of cte1, assuming that it is a nontrivial query in real life, you will have to load those results into a #temp table. You can then query those intermediate results twice - once to extract the distinct [type] values and build the dynamic SQL, and again when executing the generated SQL.
